# how to access image captured from webcam on raspberry pi windows 10 iot

Tags: file, webcam, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I want to access some files on raspberry `pi2` with windows 10 `iot` core.
I want to know how to use address for it?
in windows there are drives and directories that can be access with addresses like this `c:\a\b\c.txt`.
how is `ms-iot` file system and addresses organized?
I searched memory card also but i can't find the file that i am sure exist on it. the file is a picture grammatically captured from webcam and saved on the device by belo code

```
takePhoto.IsEnabled = false;
            recordVideo.IsEnabled = false;
            captureImage.Source = null;

            photoFile = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync(
                PHOTO_FILE_NAME, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
            ImageEncodingProperties imageProperties = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
            await mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(imageProperties, photoFile);
            takePhoto.IsEnabled = true;
            status.Text =  photoFile.Path;

            IRandomAccessStream photoStream = await photoFile.OpenReadAsync();
            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.SetSource(photoStream);
            captureImage.Source = bitmap;
```

I use the path in the `status.text` to access file but there was no file

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try accessing the local file system via its UNC path on your network. As it's a Windows OS it has the default admin shares in place.

Eg: `\\192.168.1.123\C$`

This will then prompt for the Administrator user details of the device.

Also check out this blog post for ways to get to it via the IoT Dashboard: http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/paul/2016/06/controlling-your-windows-10-iot-core-device/

Comment: thank you the address \\192.168.1.123\C$ was helpful